# @ManyToOne работает не так, как ожидалось

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Привет. 
Сама ассоциация работает правильно, но не сохраняется author_id у поста.

Много постов может быть оставлено одним автором:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
    // ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="author_id")
    private User author; }
```

Один автор может иметь много постов:

```
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;
    // ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Post> posts; }
```

Тут я пытаюсь сохранять посты:

```
@PostMapping("/posts")
    public String createPost(@Valid @RequestParam String body) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = authentication.getName();
        Post post = new Post();
        User currentUser = userService.findByName(name);
        post.setAuthor(currentUser);
        post.setBody(body);
        postService.save(post);
        return "redirect:/posts/";
    }
```

Посты сохраняются и если я искусственно (через базу добавлю правильный author_id), то ассоциация будет работать, но сам этот author_id не сохраняется. 
Почему так? Смотрю гайды типа https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne и https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/ , но не понимаю что не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить отношение и с другой стороны перед вызовом метода `save()`

```
currentUser.getPosts().add(post);
```

Comment: В таком случае выбрасывается исключение java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: Потому, что надо инициализировать список - `private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: а где инициализировать? Я попробовал прямо в поле класса User при объявлении, но исключение осталось

Comment: Я в поле делаю. Странно, что не работает.

Comment: Не сочти за наглость, но можно тебе показать проект через тимвивер? Может заметишь где ошибка :) У меня просто знакомых джавистов нет, а я уже на 2 дня застрял с этими ассоциациями

Comment: Да я сам ещё только учусь. Просто на такую же проблему напоролся недавно и мне помогла установка с двух сторон.